# Is there any support of multilingual or RTL in colResizable JQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Is there any support of multilingual or RTL in colResizable JQuery Plugin ??? 
I am unable to find on their documentation
http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/#usage

Comment: The plugin seems to be just for enhancing HTML table objects, adding column resizing features. Multilingual would not be a part of this plugin, but there are jquery plugins for translating text content, e.g. [jQuery translator](http://belelros.github.io/jqueryTranslator/)

Comment: Actually its not working fine when I select Left to right language may be there is some issue with margin or padding.

Comment: I don't want to translate it.I just want its RTL support

Answer (score 2):

:) I'm Alvaro Prieto, developer of colResizable. I am sorry, but there is no RTL compatibility yet. Maybe someday in the future!